# What HTML code do I use to center the Font Awesome icons within the features intro block of Uber on Joomla?

Tags: html, joomla, icons

I am working with the features intro block within the Uber template on Joomla.

I would like to center the Font Awesome icons, however I cannot figure out how to do this with the HTML code.

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a style to whichever tag you're using, so for example:

```
<p style="text-align: center"> your font awesome icon </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the text like so-

```
<center>YOUR TEXT HERE</center>
```

Make sure that embedded html is enabled or you'll just see the code.

Old and ugly but it still works.

Or you could find the CSS style that the text uses and add this to your CSS file.

```
   .NAME_OF_STYLE {
              text-align: center;
}
```

But this would center all the text that uses this style.
So you could use the CSS code above but create a new style then wrap any text with this HTML:

```
 <NEW_CSS_NAME> your text here! </NEW_CSS_NAME>
```